# MS Access user able to enter data but not modify it

Tags: excel, ms-access, odbc

I am trying to create an Access database that will only allow a user to enter new data through a form, but not modify that record (or the rest of the data) once it is entered. The data will then be protected and all further reports and queries will be done by another user with superior rights.

I have come to the conclusion that it is not possible to do this with Access and a simple solution has been proposed to me, and that is to enter the data through a form in Excel which will feed the information into an Access file.

Is that possible ? How ? Any better ideas ?

Thanks,
Santos

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but in general, I tend to use a different form for creating a new record than I use for editing it once it's created. However, in this case, you'd have to have all fields in both, and that seems like unnecessary duplication. You need to look into changing the AllowEdits property after a record is saved.

Answer (score 1):

You can set form properties as suggested to limit what a user can do with that form.  (Another possibility is the "Data Entry" property ... setting it to Yes would prevent them from displaying previous data in the form.)

However, if your goal is broader ("only allow a user to enter new data through a form"), you need to prevent them from opening tables in datasheet view, editable queries in datasheet view, etc.

You can distribute your application as an MDE or ACCDE format database and lock down the user interface so they can only access those features you provide with your forms and custom menus (or ribbons in 2007 or 2010).

Access also offers ULS (user level security) in the MDB database format. ULS is not supported in the newer ACCDB format ... but Access 2007 and 2010 can still use MDB format databases.  The drawbacks are that ULS is kind of fiddly to set up and not very secure.  If security is important for your application consider storing the data in a more securable database such as SQL Server.

I would choose any of those options over creating an Excel spreadsheet for data entry into an Access database.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just allow data entry using a form based on a table (though for various reasons, I would use a form based on a query of the table) - just set the properties governing deletions and modifications to 'No' and the one pertaining to additions to 'Yes'